# Observing Changes to image currentSrc Property, within Picture element

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm having some trouble with trying to get the currentSrc property of an image (only Chrome).

In particular, I'm looking at images which are part of a picture element and therefore have their src supplied by the browser. You can have an image with no src which is supplied with its src from a choice of source elements.

Like this:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 2000px)" srcset="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gears-min.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 1600px)" srcset="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com//black_hole.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Moon.jpg">
  <img style="width:100%">
</picture>
```

I'm using two methods and I'm not having any joy with either of them.

With the mutationsummary library, I'm not able to access the currentSrc property, used like this:

```
var imageObserver = new MutationSummary({
       callback: collectSource,
       queries: [ { element: 'img', elementAttributes: 'src srcset currentSrc' }]
});
```

and the same when I use a simple loop through document.getElementsByTagName('img'), like this:

```
var elementSet = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i < elementSet.length; i++) {
console.log(elementSet[i].currentSrc);
}
```

I can see logically why the mutation summary library would not work, there are no changes happening in the DOM and the mutation summary only tracks attributes, not properties.

However, I fail to see why the basic loop would not enable me to see the currentSrc using img.currentSrc. It is blank when I look at it.

The irritating thing about this is when I look at the properties of the image element in Chrome Dev Tools I can see the currentSrc property as it should be and I can see it updating. I just can't get at it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Tom, it would be easier to help you, if you showed us your current code.

Comment: Yes added some code now

Comment: What is the `basic loop`? We really need to see the actual code you're using…

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com

Comment: OK I think this was a timing issue. When my scripts were running, the images had not finished loading and so the currentSrc property was not available.  Personally I think that the mutation summary should be picking up the changes to the src or currentsrc properties, so Chrome should be writing these properties to the DOM when it performs its picture operations. Otherwise, it's a bit obscure.